# Possible frameworks / tools for building a 4x, turn-based browser game

Tags: javascript, browser, frameworks, 2d-games

**Edited. New simplified question:**

The actual core-question for me is this:
I'm starting a developement for a browser-based game. Basically the genre is 4x, turn-based game. A good example of the genre I'm going for is http://planets.nu

Can angularJS handle a browser game like this or is it just an unnecessary extra weight for the project?

**Old explanations:**

Since javascript community has enormous amount of frameworks and different libraries, it's quite overwhelming. And my cup of tea is more on the server-side PHP. So far I've pretty much come to a some conclusions, which I would want comments on.

There seems to be no browser game-frameworks suitable for these kind of games and I would most of the work have to do with some basic frameworks / libraries. Digging through and educating myself of the different JS-libraries and frameworks lately I've come to the conclusion that I'd love to use at least angularJS (or equivalent), propably jQuery to some extent, maybe Raphael (for some SVG functionality) and some other smaller libraries (like http://www.createjs.com -> PreloadJS and SoundJS.

Also if there is just a small gain of some game-framework (such as handling animations, moving the map / minimap etc.) would it really be worth the trouble? I mean the extra library, just for those seems a bit heavy. And if so, what might be a good framework for things like these (for example collision detection isn't needed at all and map will be generated with custom code).

Oh and all this is simply about the front-end, PHP is my things, so that will stick for the server-side.

The actual answers / comments I would need are opinions and suggestions which might suite a project like this. For me personally it's very challenging to pick up good tools for JS, since the selections is so huge. I'm mostly very vary of angularJS as for a fairly short introduction to it, I'm not sure if it's just not usefull enough for the project (just extra weight). But the reason for angluar is that I would rather use a framework like such, as I'm hating the basic jQuery event-handling style and would really like angulars way more (would enhance my programming rate and efficiency, since it works with my own logic better).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @harsha , you are right. I modified the actual question a lot, more to the actual point which concerns me. Is the edited version ok?